# Is ability to run shell commands limited in later versions of Android?

Tags: android, shell, command-line

Is ability to run shell commands limited in later versions of Android? Someone talked about this, however I am unable to verify. I.e, I want to use something like this:

Process myProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

Will that not be possible, or severely limited in later Android versions, e.g. Android 12?

Comment: Might have something to do with SELinux.